ReferenceError: exports is not defined in Next.JS with Dynamic Script Loading
I'm working on a Next.js React application where I need to dynamically load and use a JavaScript file hosted on an external server (which I'm unable to modify). The script contains a React component that I need to integrate into my application.
When I load script dynamically, I keep encountering the following error in my console:
ReferenceError: exports is not defined:3:23)
This is beginning of the contents of the file externalfile:
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true }); // error here

var React$1 = require('react');
var require$$1$1$1 = require('react-dom');

//...

To load the file, I use a hook shown below:
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScriptHook = (path: string): void => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `${window.location.origin}${path}`;
    script.type = 'module';
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [path]);
};

export default useScriptHook;

Here is how I use it:
// components/HomePage.tsx

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useScriptHook from './use-script-hook';

interface MyComponentProps {
  exclude?: boolean;
  isWidget?: boolean;
  color?: 'blue' | 'red';
}

type MyComponentType = React.FC<MyComponentProps>;

const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
  const [MyComponent, setMyComponent] = useState<MyComponentType | null>(null);

  useScriptHook('/api/static-assets/externalfile');

  useEffect(() => {
    if ((window as any).MyComponent) {
      setMyComponent(() => (window as any).MyComponent);
    }
  }, []);

  if (!MyComponent) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent exclude={true} isWidget={true} color="blue" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

How can I correctly load the script dynamically in a Next.js React application?
I also tried changing the script.type to text/javascript but with no success

What do you expect exports to be? You appear to be using ES modules, so there is no exports object.
